# font is applied only for English letters?

Tags: css, fonts, ionic3, tamil

Hi I am trying to use Tamil font , Which is supporting only for English letters but not for the Tamil letters 
[image]

> The dark letters are English Letters and the list is tamil letters but
>   font not applied
>
> app.scss

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'tamil-ravi';
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      src: url('../assets/fonts/ravi-b.ttf');
      src: url('../assets/fonts/ravi-b.ttf') format('embedded-opentype'),
           local('Akzidenz-Grotesk Next'),
           local('Akzidenz-Grotesk Next'),
           url('../assets/fonts/ravi-b.ttf') format('woff')
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'nagananthini';
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      src: url('../assets/fonts/nagananthini.ttf');
      src: url('../assets/fonts/nagananthini.ttf'),
           local('nagananthini Next'),
           local('nagananthini Next'),
           url('../assets/fonts/nagananthini.ttf') format('ttf')
    }

    .tamil-ravi{
        font-family: 'nagananthini';
    }
    * {
        font-family: 'tamil-ravi';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this fonts and download fonts file on zip

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'Ravi-d';
src:url('../assets/fonts/Ravi-d.eot');
src:url('../assets/fonts/Ravi-d.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../assets/fonts/Ravi-d.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('../assets/fonts/Ravi-d.woff') format('woff'),
url('../assets/fonts/Ravi-d.ttf') format('truetype');
}

font-family:'Ravi-d';
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GYZdI7em5S0iPp4sw6cYdST0Q3buFPpO

Comment: Font's applying , But i have to used tamil font 'ravi' but that does'nt applying for tamil words

Comment: @gopinath please find fonts file and  add in your project i have solve your issue 100%

Comment: it is asking for request access

Comment: Please find now or did you get it?

Comment: Where you added the fonts in which folder? and how you are calling it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170662/discussion-between-gopinath-and-ppl).